# How to change the entire layout of table from json data in flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, flutter-layout

I am using [`json_table: ^2.0.1`](https://pub.dev/packages/json_table) package for displaying JSON data in table format. It is working fine, but I need that table format to be different.

Code:

```
class CompareInverters1State extends State<CompareInverters1> {
  final String jsonSample = '[{"name":"Ram","age":23 },'
      '{"name":"Shyam", "age":18 },'
      '{"name":"John", "age":10 }]';
  bool toggle = true;
  List<JsonTableColumn>? columns;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    columns = [
      JsonTableColumn("name", label: "Name"),
      JsonTableColumn("age", label: "Age"),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var json = jsonDecode(jsonSample);
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            JsonTable(
              json,
              columns: columns,
              showColumnToggle: true,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 16.0,
            ),
            Text(
              getPrettyJSONString(jsonSample),
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  String getPrettyJSONString(jsonObject) {
    JsonEncoder encoder = new JsonEncoder.withIndent('  ');
    String jsonString = encoder.convert(json.decode(jsonObject));
    return jsonString;
  }

  String eligibleToVote(value) {
    if (value >= 18) {
      return "Yes";
    } else
      return "No";
  }
}
```

Output:
[image]

But I need to show the table as follows:

[image]

What changes are required?

Comment: You can use `DataTable` after parsing JSON.

Comment: I want to use json_table package.  Any changes in above code?

Comment: I don't know(think) using `tableHeaderBuilder` or `tableCellBuilder` will be easy to create the view you want. Rather, parse the JSON and represent data using `DateTable` the way like, it is more flexible than `json_table`.

Comment: Okay I will try to implement using DataTable. Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use this package try creating a class. then use the default Table of the flutter material library.

```
DataTable(  
  columns: [  
    DataColumn(label: Text(json.first.key) ),  
     for(String something in json.first)
     DataColumn(label: Text(something['name']) )),  

    DataColumn(label: Text(json[1].key) ),  
     for(String something in json[1])
     DataColumn(label: Text(something['age']) )),  
  ],  
  rows: [  
    //or map your data here
  ],  
),
```

Comment: Does default table have column filter option ?    Json_table gives option of column filter.